# How to solve the problems that html page works well in firefox and chrome, but wrong with IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I meet a problem that my page works well in firefox and chrome(almost the same look and feel) but very bad in IE. It's time consuming to adjust the differences. Is there any research has been done already to tell the differenceS, or any automation tool to examine the uncompatibilities?

BTW: which tool you guys are using when debugging in IE(like firebug for IE)?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. You'll get better answers if you ask a specific question about a specific problem you're having.

Comment: This is an eternal struggle. You'd better get used to learning the differences and dealing with them (and that only comes with a lot of pain).

Comment: Can you recommend a tool for me to use with IE? Like firebug

Comment: @Paul - while it's broad, I think it's a relevant question if it can be answered with general approaches to a problem that sooooo many of us face...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best starting point is to always use some kind of "reset mechanism" like [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or framework like [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com), they help in reducing differences between browsers (not all, but most of it). If this is not possible (project is already in finishing phase, etc.) you can always ask questions here, check [Position Is Everything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/) for description of bugs, [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), [SitePoint reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) and various other sites (Google is your friend :)). Hope this helps.

There is "debugging" tool for IE - [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) - but it's usefulness can't compare to that of Firebug, Dragonfly and such. IE8+ does have better support for debugging, though… There are some articles that suggest [using Visual Studio](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-techniques-in-ie-6/), but I haven't tried it. Mostly it's just trial and error with IE :).

Answer (score 3):

[ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) is a JavaScript file that automatically fixes many Internet Explorer bugs for all versions. Works like magic.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the tiresome world of IE.

**IE8** has some version of developers tools, hit `F12` on your keyboard and it will pop up. (not present in 6&7)

There are many documented bugs in IE, a simple [Google Search](http://www.google.no/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=IE+bugs) would help you out better, but a lot cannot be accounted for until you have your site working in FF.

What most developers I know do is to make the site in FF, make small changes for Webkit browsers then go over to IE (not including 6) and debug.

In my experience there really is no way to tell what IE is going to mess up next, so you'll probably just have to deal with it as it happens.

Comment: I believe that you need to specifically install IE Developer Tools for IE6/7, but hitting `F12` in a native install won't do anything except in IE8.

Comment: @ Jonathan Day; that's why I said "IE8 has some version of..."

Answer (score 2):

For fast and better results in IE you can use CSS Hacks for adjusting the HTML elements.

For IE we have IE Developer AddOn

you can download it here : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535